# Selecting a method using different enable_if conditions

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20

I want to write a generic validate function. So i tried writing a meta program.
But it does not gets compiled, and rightly so. Can anyone tell me a way to achieve it.

I am posting my sample code. There can be 3 or more types of structs (here A, B, C), some having a particular type of header, another having other type of header and some even not having a header. So i want to write a program which correctly choose the required function (here f1(), f2() to validate a struct header. I don't want to use Boost Hana or any other reflection library.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Header
{
    int i;
};

struct OrderHeader
{
    int i; int j;
};

struct A
{
    Header header;
    int val;
};

struct B
{
    OrderHeader order_header;
    int val;
    int c;
};

struct C
{
    int val;
    int c;
};

bool f1(Header h)
{
    return h.i == 1 ? true : false;
}

bool f2(OrderHeader oh)
{
    return (oh.i == 1 and oh.j == 1) ? true : false;
}

template<typename St, typename = enable_if_t<is_same_v<decltype(St::header), Header>>>
using v1 = bool;

template<typename St, typename = enable_if_t<is_same_v<decltype(St::order_header), OrderHeader>>>
using v2 = bool;

template<typename St>
bool validate(St s)
{    
    if constexpr(is_same_v<v1<St>, bool>)
    {
        return f1(s.header);
    }
    else if constexpr(is_same_v<v2<St>, bool>)
    {
        return f2(s.order_header);
    }
    
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{         
    A at{1,1};
    A af{};
    C c{};    
    B b{};
    
    cout << boolalpha << validate(at) << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << validate(af) << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << validate(b) << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << validate(c) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if constexpr` can be a means for partial compilation, but the condition inside `if` must always be compilable. In your case `v1<St>` and `v2<St>` only exist when `St` is of the right type, hence the errors.

You can use specialization of variable templates instead, e.g. like this

```
template<typename, typename = void>
constexpr bool is_v1 = false;

template<typename St>
constexpr bool is_v1<St, enable_if_t<is_same_v<decltype(St::header), Header>>> = true;

template<typename, typename = void>
constexpr bool is_v2 = false;

template<typename St>
constexpr bool is_v2<St, enable_if_t<is_same_v<decltype(St::order_header), OrderHeader>>> = true;

template<typename St>
bool validate(St s)
{
    if constexpr (is_v1<St>)
    {
        return f1(s.header);
    }
    else if constexpr (is_v2<St>)
    {
        return f2(s.order_header);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now `is_v1<St>` and `is_v2<St>` always return some value (either `true` or `false`), and the code should compile<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> There's also a typo in `f2()`: `oh.i == 1 and oh.j == 1` should be `oh.i == 1 && oh.j == 1`.

Also note `h.i == 1 ? true : false` is tautologous, just `h.i == 1` is enough.

Comment: Thanks bro for the answer. It resolved my problem. I was under wrong impression that if a condition cant be evaluated constexpr if leaves that one.  Also 'and' was not typo its synonym for &&. 2nd point accepted, just overlooked that :)